# Unix: replace every odd | with \left| and every even | with \right|

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk

An enormous equation. You need to add `\left|` on the left side of corresponding `|`. The corresponding `|` you need to replace with `\right|`.

**Equation**

```
\begin{equation}
| \Delta w_{0} | = \frac{|w_{0}|}{2} \left( |\frac{\Delta g}{g}|+|\frac{\Delta (\Delta r)}{\Delta r}| + |\frac{\Delta r}{r}| +|\frac{\Delta L}{L}| \right)
\end{equation}
```

**[Premises]**

1. The amount of `|` is even.
2. No nesting. So scenario such as `M_OPEN|----X_OPEN|-----X_CLOSED|------M_CLOSED|` is not possible, just `M_OPEN|---M_CLOSED|---H_OPEN|----H_CLOSED|`.

Comment: You problem does not give a unique solution. |||||||| can be ()()()()()(), (())()(), (())(()), ((()))() etc. We can write a program to give you all possible solutions and you pick the right one otherwise you have to do it manually.

Comment: `\langle \psi | \psi \rangle`?

Comment: Use something like `\newcommand{\alr}[3]{\left#1#2\right#3}\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\alr||{#1}}\newcommand{\lr}[1]{\alr(){#1}}` instead of `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed -r -e 's/\|([^|]+)\|/\\left|\1\\right|/g'
```

But this works only if you do not have nested |...|.